# how to address Python module inspect not having function getcallargs

Tags: python, virtualenv, inspect

I am trying to use the module `inspect` in two different environments. In one of the environments, everything is fine. In the other, `inspect` appears to be missing the function `getcallargs`. I am not sure what's going wrong. I'm also not sure how to check the version of `inspect` that is being used in each environment. How can I get `inspect` to work in the problematic environment?

The environment that works fine is as follows:

```
user1@computer1:~>python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import inspect
>>> print inspect.getcallargs
<function getcallargs at 0x7ff122c0a578>
```

The environment that breaks is as follows:

```
(virtual_environment)-bash-4.1$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jan 23 2014, 10:39:35) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import inspect
>>> print inspect.getcallargs
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getcallargs'
```

Comment: The [python Documentation for Inspect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#classes-and-functions) indicate that `inspect.getcallargs`  was added in 2.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 2.6 the inspect module does not have the getcallargs function.

https://docs.python.org/release/2.6/library/inspect.html

Python 2.7 does have getcallargs

https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html